# Подключение к MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Есть сайт на стеке Node.js + MongoDB. Работа с Mongo осуществляется через mongoose. Это подключение к базе.

```
const options = {
       useNewUrlParser: true,
       family: 4
    };

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/clients', options)
        .then(console.log('MongoDB has started ...'))
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Проблема в том, что при подключении других пользователей к сайту, у них он не работает корректно. Как я понял из-за того, что в ConnectionString стоит localhost. Но если я поменяю его на адрес свой машины в локальной сети, то выдает такую ошибку. Все подключения к сайту исключительно в рамках локальной сети.

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.25:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Подскажите, как настроить подключение к базе и в чем проблема?

Comment: при каждом обращении к БД вы создаете новое подключение?

Comment: Я думаю, нет. Так как Промис срабатывает всего один раз, при запуске сервера.

Comment: Уточните вопрос: "при подключении других пользователей у НИХ он не работает корректно" - а у кого работает корректно?

Comment: Уточняю. При подключении к сайту идет запрос к базе, извлекаются данные и на их основе рендерится шаблон. Так вот, данный сайт работает только на моей машине. Так как на ней велась разработка все обращения проходили по адресу localhost. Так вот, что бы фронт корректно работал я поменял localhost на адрес свой локальной машины в сети. Bсе работает, но когда доходит до момента обращения к базе данный вылетает error представленный выше.

Comment: Если подводить итоги вышесказанного, то сайт работает только на мой машине. До того как я перешел на хранилище данных MongoDB я использовал простенькую библиотеку для файловой БД JSON. И что бы другие юзеры в рамках мой локальной сети могли подключится на мой сайт, мне достаточно было во всех запросах поменять localhost на адрес в сети и все работало у всех. Но после перехода на Mongo столкнулся с данной проблемой

Comment: вообщем, я запутался.... что, куда Вы меняете и главное зачем.... Вы что, запросы в БД прямо с фронта отправляете? Не через сервер?

Comment: Крч конкретно у меня на машине сайт работает исправно. Но когда к нему пытаются подключится другие пользователи в рамкой ЛКС, то у них на сайте нет контента, а консоль мне выдаёт ошибку которую я указал выше.

Comment: Все что было описано выше в комментариях было для полноты видимости картины, но оно только сбило с толку)

Comment: Я думал что проблема в коде выше, в том, что в строке у меня указан localhost. Поменял на свой ip, но это не решило проблему)

Comment: в конфигурации MongoDB, установите параметр `net.bindIpAll: true` - возможно ошибка исчезнет. Если нет - удалите это изменение . https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIpAll

Comment: Спасибо) Это решило мою проблему))